# WHMCS addon not showing in modules

Tags: whmcs

whmcs-addon-whois-0.2 addon is not showing in whmcs> Setup> Addon modules, after uploading and uzipping its file in public> whmcs> Modules> Addons. Where am I getting it wrong?

Please advise.

Comment: Is this open source? if so please share the url. If not, share the file names. and add the definition code. e.g. function addonmodule_config()

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your addon module folder name and  addon module file name is same.Also confirm there function name as same.